# Slow compilation for Project Euler 10

Tags: python-3.x, primes

I am new to this. I was trying question number ten of the Project Euler Question Bank Archive. My code looks fine to me but it is not efficient. I am not sure, how I can make this quick. My code is as follows.

```
def isPrimeNum(num):
    for i in range(2, num):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def main():
    listOfPrimes = []
    sum = 0
    upperLim = 2000000

    for i in range(2, upperLim):
        if isPrimeNum(i) == True:
            sum += i
        else:
            continue
main()
```

Comment: StackOverflow is a nice place to ask questions regarding help with programming and algorithmic problems, but if you already have a working demo of your code, maybe try asking [CodeReview (StackExchange)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), I've seen that they can be very helpful in finding ways to optimize people's code.

Answer (score 0):

When you check whether a number is a prime in `isPrimeNum` function use `for i in range(2, int(num ** .5) + 1)` instead of your current version of the for-loop. It works because all unique divisors of n are numbers less than or equal to sqrt(n). Check "Primality test" article on wikipedia.

With this modificaton you will get significant acceleration. Results on my machine:

```
# old version
%timeit main(20_000)
1.36 s ± 2.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# new version
%timeit main(20_000)
26.5 ms ± 79.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```